# Auto fill range of cells with different values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, autofill

I am a self-taught beginner...
I made a dynamic drop down menu for a Chinese name database from G:S. Everything was working fine, but my problem is that there will be more names added into J:J in the future, and I want to find a way to quickly categorize them.

See A:E for example using English words
I can easily use "sort" and "left" formulas if it's in English.
But what if it's not.

I tried this formula to find the row numbers of the letters in E:E, but I don't know how to auto fill D:D with that information.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR("E"&MATCH(A2:A,E:E,0)))
```

please help my poor brain.

[image: 1]

Comment: see screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzHBJ.jpg

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l4YACeNd4mBH4_INxgpUEGwbOH8njB73EQQpaxtXLV8/edit?usp=sharing